# taxonomie children wordpress woocommerce product_variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

my problem is to get the children of variation in WooCommerce/Wordpress.

There should be (WooDocs) a taxonomy product_variation but this fails…

```
$term_children = get_terms('product_variation',$term_id);
```

with:

```
$variation_ids = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
```

i get the first Level of Variations, and I guess could get my $term_id per attribute_id for get_terms …

output from $variation_ids:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [attribute_id] => 1
        [attribute_name] => aufzucht
        [attribute_label] => Aufzucht
        [attribute_type] => select
        [attribute_orderby] => menu_order
        [attribute_public] => 0
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [attribute_id] => 2
        [attribute_name] => groesse
        [attribute_label] => Größe
        [attribute_type] => select
        [attribute_orderby] => menu_order
        [attribute_public] => 0
    )

)
```

I am honestly little confused. :/

What I want is just a tree of attributes and its Variation-types.

Grösse (size) fE. should have small/medium/large as children/variation-types.

Thx,

tom

Comment: i see at https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-attribute-functions.php there is a $attribute->get_variations() … ?

Comment: get_terms is right! Use the pa_ prefix to get taxonomy… pa_groesse

Answer (score 0):

get_terms is right, but use the pa_ prefix in the attribute/taxionomy name!

```
$term_children = get_terms('pa_groesse');
```